# copy enum array

Tags: java, enums

Hi I have a enum array and it is a field of my class. And I am implementing clone method of this class. But I have some ideas about copying array of enums but what is the formal way of copying an enum array ?

```
   public enum StateEnum {
      START, PLAY, PAUSE , STOP
   }


class MyClass{
    StateEnum[] stateEnums;

    public Object clone(){
      MyClass copyClass = new MyClass();
      // copy enums
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enum values are (or should be) immutable, so you don't need to copy them.
You can just make a shallow copy of the array by calling `System.arraycopy()`.

Comment: Enum values are not immutable, but there is only a single instance of each one.  A shallow copy is still correct, but you should remove the comment about their being immutable.

Comment: @increment1: Why aren't they immutable?

Comment: @SLaks Because you can give them mutable state and methods to mutate it. `enum Foo { BAR; public int mutable; }`

Comment: An enum value is an instance of a class, you can define that class to have a mutable field and setter if you so desire (not normally a good idea, but you can do it).  In fact, using an enum to implement the singleton design pattern is one recommended way to implement singletons.

Answer (score 1):

As said by SLaks, use the `System.arraycopy` to clone your array. Further, the

```
MyClass copyClass = new MyClass();
```

should be replaced by

```
MyClass copyClass = (MyClass)super.clone();
```

The reason for this is explained in [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-1999/jw-01-object.html) in full detail, where the end of page 2 discusses the common pitfalls while implementing a `clone` method